# yii-user extension, how to create a new relationship properly?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hello everyone and thanks for reading , i have  little problem , i installed the yii user extension.
I created another table that has a relationship with the user table.
Yii created the relationships with the "user" table automatically but when i try to use the relationship it gives me the below message;

> include(Users.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Could this be because User Model is not with the other models but instead in Modules/User.....
How can i make it work ? 
eg

```
 array(
            'header' => __('Title'),
            'name' => 'id_employer_contract',
            'value' => '$data->user->username',//user is the name of relationship

        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to access the User.php model from outside of the User module, the file has not been imported yet.

If you look at the init() method of the UserModule.php file, you'll see that the User.php file gets imported via the `user.models.*` statement.

There are a few different way to import this file from other parts of your system:

- Add `application.modules.user.models.*` to the import section of your main.php. This will make it available everywhere in your application
- Call `Yii::import('application.modules.user.models.*');` right before the area of code depending on User.php
- Call `Yii::app()->getModule('user');` right before the area of code depending on User.php. This will call the init() method in the User module.

Comment: hey , i tried implementing your first solution and this is the error i get Alias "user.models.*" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file. My import alreaddy imports the  'application.modules.user.models.*',
                'application.modules.user.components.*',

Comment: It looks like I was mistaken. The module's alias only gets created when the module itself is instantiated. Does importing `application.modules.user.models.*` solve the problem?

Comment: Hey , no it dose not its already imported. You have any other ideas i could try ?

Comment: @Gunnit It looks like your relation is trying to use a class called `Users.php`. It should be `User.php` without the "s".

Answer (score 0):

Look at `"include(Users.php): failed"`

You can change the relation mapping (auto generated by Gii) from this:

`'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id')`

To this:

`'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id')`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In another version of Yii the according model might be `YumUser` instead of `User` when creating your relation, did the job for me: 
`'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'YumUser', 'user_id')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is that the Table name for users is called "users" so when yii is resolving this for model generation it would resolve the user model to be "Users" however the yii-user module extension has the model as "UserModel" in a file named User.php 
This means that in essesnce the file named Users.php does not exist.

To resolve this just change the relationship in your new model to`'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'User'),` and not `'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'User'),`